# Process data n times with a template and use a counter in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I want to process an xml n times and map the counter of the current run in the XML. The XSLT below works perfectly fine for XSLT 1.0, but when I set the stylesheet/@version attribute to "2.0". Something strange happens:

The code works fine until "count"=8. When "count"=9 it runs 90 times and when count="10" or higher it runs 1 time and from "count"=20 or higher it runs two times and so on. Why is that so? How could I implement such a function in XSLT 2.0?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <Klammer> 
      <xsl:call-template name="selects"> 
        <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>  
        <xsl:with-param name="count">13</xsl:with-param> 
      </xsl:call-template> 
    </Klammer> 
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template name="selects"> 
    <xsl:param name="i"/>  
    <xsl:param name="count"/>  
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count"> 
      <xsl:call-template name="myRepeatedTemplate"> 
        <xsl:with-param name="number">
          <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
        </xsl:with-param> 
      </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:if>  
    <!--begin_: RepeatTheLoopUntilFinished-->  
    <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count"> 
      <xsl:call-template name="selects"> 
        <xsl:with-param name="i"> 
          <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/> 
        </xsl:with-param>  
        <xsl:with-param name="count"> 
          <xsl:value-of select="$count"/> 
        </xsl:with-param> 
      </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template name="myRepeatedTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>  
    <xsl:element name="Testelement"> 
      <xsl:element name="Testnumber"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$number"/> 
      </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:element> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please state which processor you use, it is an XSLT 1.0 processor or an XSLT 2 or 3 processor?

Comment: In general I would think that doing `<xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>` instead of the nested `xsl:with-param/xsl:value-of` will avoid the problem, as I ssuppose it is caused by some change of processing from standards mode to forwards or backwards compatible mode, depending on whether you use an XSLT 1 or 2 processor.

Comment: Hey, thank you the change in the code solved the problem!

Comment: Do note that in XSLT 2.0 you could simplify your code significantly by using `xsl:for each select="1 to $n"`.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a string comparison in `test="$i &lt;= $count"` rather than a numeric comparison, which is a consequence of (a) using declarations like

```
<xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
```

rather than

```
<xsl:with-param name="i" select="1"/>
```

and (b) failing to declare data types: you should use

```
<xsl:param name="i" as="xs:integer"/>
```

If the stylesheet says `version="1.0"` then an XSLT 2.0 processor will run in "backwards compatibility mode" (XSLT 1.0 always did a numeric comparison for operators such as `<=`); this changes when you set `version="2.0"`, with the effect that comparing two strings compares them as strings, not by converting to numbers.